# Oracle PL/SQL Procedure Table Code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I've a table users on my oracle database:

```
|------|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|  ID  |     NAME     |          EMAIL          |    BIRTHDAY    |
|------|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|  1   |     Joe      |       joe@test.com      |   1986-10-13   |
|------|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|  2   |    Julie     |     julie@test.com      |   1990-05-07   |
|------|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
|  3   |     Dan      |       dan@test.com      |   1988-10-20   |
|------|--------------|-------------------------|----------------|
```

How to create the procedure pr_export() that will return:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(50), EMAIL VARCHAR2(50), BIRTHDAY DATE,  CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (1, 'Joe', 'joe@test.com', to_date(1986-10-13, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (2, 'Julie', 'julie@test.com', to_date(1990-05-07, 'YYYY-MM-DD')); 
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (3, 'Dan', 'dan@test.com', to_date(1988-10-20, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I read a tip that I can use like:

```
select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'USERS';
```

and cursors but I have no idea how to create the procedure.

Thank you!!!

Comment: What is the problem in doing `SELECT * FROM USERS` if you want to fetch all the rows from the `Users` table?

Comment: I don't know how to create a procedure to manipulate the data return. Eg If the value is a date, i have to add text to_date( ... )

Comment: So, your quesrtion is "How do I write PL/SQL code?"  That's a bit too broad.  If you do some reading, make some attempts, then ask us for specific help on a specific problem, I think you'll get a better response.

Comment: It's a nice excercise if you want to learn pl/sql, but otherwise I would use the export function of an sql editor or search the internet for such a basic procedure

Comment: @winkbrace: its that i need. Ive already made a search, but i cant find =( Im very new at pl/sql, so its very hard for me =(

Comment: So basically you want a function that you hand a table name to and it returns a `CREATE TABLE` statement and a bunch of `INSERTs` to populate the table, is that correct?

Comment: @Bob Jarvis right! ;) but its a procedure, not function ^^

Comment: And why does it have to be a procedure rather than a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of your procedure `pr_export()` could use the `DBMS_METADATA`-Interface:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','USERS') FROM dual;
```

The output will look like:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS" ("ID" NUMBER, "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), "BIRTHDAY" DATE)
```

You can tweak the output with parameters like:

```
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'STORAGE',false);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'REF_CONSTRAINTS', FALSE);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'CONSTRAINTS', FALSE);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'PRETTY',FALSE);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'SQLTERMINATOR',TRUE);
```

More info on: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm

To use `dbms_metadata.set_transform_param` outside of a procedure, just surround it with an anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(...);
END;
/
```

Comment: how could i use set_transfor_parm ? I put above and below select command, but i got error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement